# Rails Problems with IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got several problems with a Rails 4.2.1 and Ruby 2.1 application in actual IE. If I save something to a database and do a redirect, the values are saved twice in the database.

Does anyone have this as well?

Save Methode in controller:

```
if request.post?
  @question.attributes = params[:question]
  if @question.save
    flash.now[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
    update_answers params
    redirect_after_save @question
  end
end


 def update_answers params
if !params[:add].nil?
  params[:add].each do | id, data |
    answer = Answer.new
    data[:question_id] = @question.id
    answer.update_attributes data
  end
end
end


def redirect_after_save q

if params[:action_after_save] == 'back'
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
  redirect_to :controller => :lessons, :action => :edit, :id => q.lesson_id
end
if params[:action_after_save] == 'new'
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
  redirect_to :action => :new, :id => q.lesson_id
end
if params[:action_after_save] == 'test'
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
  redirect_to :action => :test, :id => q.id
end
end
```

Comment: did you try looking at the development logs and see if if it is actually making two queries / post requests?  if yes,  does this happen when you hit save button once?

Comment: I checked it up. And yes there are two queries in dev log. And yes its post form. added code above.

Comment: Are you using TurboLinks?

Comment: don't think so what is turbo links?

Comment: Maybe provide the method definitions of `update_answers` and `redirect_after_save`. It's likely that one of those two methods are saving, you already saved when you checked `if @questions.save` and if you save again, that would be twice.

Comment: I've added the code above

Comment: Add debugger / byebug before your save and just travel through the entire block

Comment: Try disabling turbolinks. Here's how : http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

Comment: Don't have the gem turbolink in my gemfile ...

Comment: Are there any other hints where the problem comes from?